# How to prevent null value from being stored as part of List

Tags: java, lombok

How to prevent null value from being stored as part of List. ignoreNullCollections is not helping here. I want null value to be ignored, no exception should be thrown even if its passed as part of the Singular method call

```
import lombok.Singular;

@Singular(ignoreNullCollections = true)
List<Foo> foos;
```

Answer (score 2):

That is so far removed from the kind of boilerplate that lombok is intended to bust, that it is not supported and (as core contributor, I think I can say this): Probably never will.

Normally you can write whichever parts of a builder you want to replace by hand and lombok will just add whatever you left out, but you can't write parts of the `@Singular` infrastructure because it is non-intuitive. Thus, your only real option is to make a constructor that strips nulls out of the `List<Foo>` parameter you recieve prior to assigning it to your field, and then putting `@Builder` on that instead.

Comment: I just add one element at a time like this .foo(foo) and I wouldnt want a null value to be added

Comment: Yes, I understand. This is too far removed from common usage to support. Throwing an NPE if null is added - yeah that seems reasonable, but, in general ,'if null, do nothing silently' is a giant code smell. We try not to add support for boneheaded code style.

Comment: I will have to do null checks before adding the value then, which makes it more verbose. If there isn't a way, I will have to add this just don't have a choice since null values as part of a List doesn't make sense

Comment: Generally when code is doing things that makes no sense, you should not 'silently ignore', you should throw an exception. Who is trying to add nulls to a list? Why do you think it is appropriate to presume 'surely they meant: Eh, just do nothing'?